# how to load a html page in web Browser control that contains java script

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

how to load a html page in web Browser control that contains java script .

http://unicodetoisoconverter.appspot.com/test.html

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://unicodetoisoconverter.appspot.com/test.html"));
webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
```

I am tried like this but the page is not get loaded it shows only a white color the alert is not getting

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, but you should set `IsScriptEnabled` to true **before** starting the navigation.

Comment: yes i tried this but same issue               webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
 webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://unicodetoisoconverter.appspot.com/test.html"));